# Webrtc: Unable to retrieve TURN server

Tags: ios, webrtc, apprtcdemo, apprtc

I am trying to use webrtc.framework along with libAppRTCMobile_lib.a for making a native app same as AppRTCMobile for ios. While calling connectToRoomWithId we are getting the below message. Please help me why TURN server is giving the below error message.

"(ARDAppClient.m:234 -[ARDAppClient connectToRoomWithId:settings:isLoopback:]_block_invoke): Error retrieving TURN servers: The request timed out."

Code Snippet:

```
ARDSettingsModel *settingsModel = [[ARDSettingsModel alloc] init];
self.client = [[ARDAppClient alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[self.client connectToRoomWithId:self.roomName
                        settings:settingsModel
                      isLoopback:NO];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Plain WebRTC does not have "rooms", so you might want to add some tags with the libraries you're using.

Comment: Please can you elaborate more.

Comment: Are you using a "free" turn server from a list off the internet? If so, then that's your problem. There are no free turn servers.

Comment: I am using turn:numb.viagenie.ca turn server